# XMLTRANSFORM with gt; operator

Tags: oracle, xslt

I'm using ORACLE XMLTRANSFORM function in order to convert an XML file using an XSL file.

In my XSL file, I got this part of code :

```
                  <xsl:element name="recurrent">
                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="($annee_int&gt;$annee_obs) and ($annee_int!=&apos;&apos;) and ($annee_obs!=&apos;&apos;)">O</xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>N</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                  </xsl:element>
                  <xsl:element name="anneeIntegration">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$annee_int"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                  <xsl:element name="anneeObservation">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$annee_obs"/>
                  </xsl:element>
```

And got this result :

```
            <recurrent>O</recurrent>
            <anneeIntegration>2018</anneeIntegration>
            <anneeObservation>2019</anneeObservation>
```

I don't understand why recurrent="O" instead of recurrent="N".
Using Altova and same input files, my colleague got recurrent="N".

I made several tries and I think the problem comes from the operator **"gt;"**. But I still cannot explain why I got this result.

Comment: Please edit your post with a [minimum, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including fuller input XML example and fuller XSLT script (not snippets). Simply, we need to see the full context to know `$` variables and XPaths to help understand your logic.

Comment: I found the explanation by myself. Got my variables "anneeIntegration" and "anneeObservation" using "substring" on other variables so I need to cast them number($annee_int)&gt;number($annee_obs). Thank you for your answer. I'll keep your advices in mind for next topics.

Comment: From what I can see from here you try to figure out if annee_int and annee_obs is empty (or not defined) `($annee_int!=&apos;&apos;)`. I would guess that this might not work. But please show your input as @Parfait already suggested

Comment: Remember StackOverflow serves for future readers, too, beyond original posters. Setting up a more readable question with sample data and script can help other XSLT coders who encounter your same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my XSL, I need to cast variables as numbers :

**number**($annee_int)&gt;**number**($annee_obs)

Comment: This indicates a non-conforming processor. According to the [XPath 1.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans), when comparing two strings using the `<` operator, *"the objects are compared by converting both objects to numbers and comparing the numbers"*. There should be no need for explicit conversion.

Comment: P.S I'd suggest you simplify your code by using [literal result elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#literal-result-element) instead of `xsl:element`.